# android Handle big Picture firebase notification in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have an android application and I tried to add big picture to notification.
My issue that the big picture is working when the app is in foreground but when app is in background or closed the notification is received without picture.

My code:

```
intentNotification.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 50, intentNotification, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
    .setContentTitle(dataTitle)
    .setContentText(dataBody)
    //.setLargeIcon(getBitmapicon(getApplicationContext()))        
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
    //.setLargeIcon(icon(getApplicationContext()))
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
    .bigPicture(image))
    .setLights(Color.LTGRAY, 1000, 1000)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setTicker(dataTitle)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
nManager.notify((int) SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive notification messages they are handled automatically by Firebase when your application is in background.
If you want to handle messages in background then they should have a data payload.

Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: how it handle automatically? this is my json !! "data":{
     "mediaUrl":"",
      "data_title":"",
      "data_body":"",
      "screen_id":"21"
      "badge":1
       "bigPicture":"https://static.pexels.com/photos/4825/red-love-romantic-flowers.jpg"

    },